# Saving 2 variable's values for later use

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I tried to make the title of this most the most descriptive as possible, as I don't know how to do this... I know the best way will be value storage in some form of array.

My question is this, I have this query where I need to pic the tag name and the correspondent id for a later comparison and use (`$tag_nome` is collected by `$_GET`):

```
$resultado2 = mysql_query("SELECT tag.tag_nome, rel_frasetag.id_tag 
                           FROM tag, rel_frasetag 
                           WHERE rel_frasetag.id_tag = tag.id_tag AND                                                                                                                  
                                 rel_frasetag.id_frase='$id_frase'") or die(mysql_error());

while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado2))
{   
    $tag_nome2 = utf8_encode($res2['tag_nome']);
    $id_tag    = $res2['id_tag'];
}
```

I already tried some things like `array_push()` but couldn't get it to work.

At the end of this snippet I'm comparing `$tag_nome2` against `$tag_nome` to see if they match. If so, it will echo one link with the corresponding `$tag_nome2` and `$id_tag`, and  if not will echo pretty much the same thing, with a different class on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess as far as what you want to do is the following:

```
if( $tag_nome2 == $id_tag )
{
  // do something
}
else
{
  // no match
}
```

Perhaps though, you're saying your variable names are being overwritten? You're inside of a while loop, so the values they'll ultimately receive will be that of $res2[] at the end of the last iteration of your loop.

And if you're saying you want to save your rows for later, you can do:

```
$holder = array();

$res = mysql_query("");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
{
  $holder[] = $row;
}

print_r($holder);
```

Comment: that's what I had so far... but that forces me to have the mysql code in the middle of the html and I wanted to kind of separate it. My best and initial guess was to put the values I wanted into an array so I could compare them later. And this way having no while(mysql code) mixed with the HTML portion of the site

Comment: @AfonsoGomes: You can do just that with this code, to some degree. If you know how many rows you'll have, you can access them with $holder[$n][$key];, but if the amount is unknown, you'll have to loop, period.

Comment: Unknown amout of rows get by the query ... for now the maximum number is 4 but can grow bigger with time :)